Uzbek language in Ubuntu language-support
Why Ubuntu don't support Uzbek language? There have tadjik and kazakh language in scale Central Asia. But Uzbekistan population more than their.

This is the list of translated languages for 24.04 and you will note the current status of Uzbek here. Access to the Ubuntu language pack builders is here. I doubt this is a question that can be answered on Ask Ubuntu and will only be opinion based and thus off-topic

Let's look at the current status of Uzbek translations in Ubuntu 24.04: (source)[red = untranslated]


Only 38 contributors of Uzbek translations, each averaging only about 10-12 strings.
Translations are a Community task (that means not provided by Canonical). If a community wants translations, that community must organize itself and do the work.
We welcome new translation volunteers! Your contribution helps make Ubuntu (and all Free Software) better for everyone.
Start your translation journey at https://ubuntu.com/community/contribute/translation-localisation
